# Excel formula to output all numbers in a given range

Tags: date, excel-formula

For a product compatibility sheet, I need to convert data in the form of year-year (e.g. 1997-2004) to a list of all years in that range (1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004) with spaces. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I feel like this may be easy, but I'm by no means an excel expert. Thanks!

Comment: From @james-chen: so A1 = 1997-2000 and A2 you want 1997 1998 1999 2000 all in that 1 cell?

Comment: another question, does it need to be formula or is VBA ok?

Comment: Either one is ok! Thanks for your answer! It looks good, I won't be in the office for a bit, but will add it in as soon as I get back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the data all in 1 cell and ahs to be formula driven then i have a work around for you, not pretty but works
the below formula was tested on 1997-1999 range so if you have 1997-2007 then you'll need to add to the formula Left(A1,4)+4...+5....+6 etc.  and you would need to do this for the largest range, i.e largest range is 1997-2007 then ever cell needs to have the formula go up to left(A1,4)+11

```
   =LEFT(A1,4)&" "&IF(LEFT(A1,4)+1>Value(RIGHT(A1,4)),"",LEFT(A1,4)+1)&" "&IF(LEFT(A1,4)+2>Value(RIGHT(A1,4)),"",LEFT(A1,4)+2)&" "&IF(LEFT(A1,4)+3>Value((A1,4)),"",LEFT(A1,4)+3)
```

The other way would be doing it by cell, a little less messy.  so A1 is the range and lets say your largest span is 10 years then you'll need 10 columns to the right.  so let's use 1997-1999 A1 as an example then in B1 you want
    =LEFT(A1,4)
just to give you the start year
then in C1 you want

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1+1>VALUE(RIGHT($A1,4)),"",B1+1),"")
```

then just drag it to whatever the last column is.  so  largest range 1997-199 then last cell is D1, if its 1997-2000 then E1, etc etc.

now in cell E1(or whatever last cell +1 is) put

```
=B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1
```

i like the last method if your not comfortable nesting formulas

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. You have enough rep [to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and have flagged this post for deletion.